# Flash content not displayed on localhost

Tags: web-services, flash, security, web

I have Apache Tomcat 8 running JSP application. On the root webpage there is a flash component that should access the microphone. 
The page is displayed ok in the web, but on the localhost I can see just a white space instead of the component. I added C:\ to the trusted locations, I allowed the access in the local Flash settings as well as in global ones... Nothing helps.

The crossdomain.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM "http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain- policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
    <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all" />
    <allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>
    <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

In the server logs I can see that the component is accessed fine (code 200), I can access it directly from the browser (I tried Chrome, FF, IE). But the content of the component is not displayed. I tried to embed another test component, everth works fine with it.

Could anybody please give me a hint what might be wrong?

Comment: dunno if this is relevant, but `http://localhost` is a different origin from `file://`

Comment: Could you clarify your point?